# Write to file, keep changes and append to them

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have a program that creates values for the matrix `u`, and this changes for every iteration `f`, I want to write out the value of `u(2,2)` for every iteration `f`. So for example `u(2,2)=5  f=1`,   `u(2,2)=9  f=2`, and so on.

Now `test(u,n,f)` only writes the last value.When it have met my criteria to stop the do loop. I don't want my subroutine to overwrite the file plot.txt every time, I want it to keep `u(2,2)` for every iterations. I want it to look like this

```
5  1

9  2

10 3
```

but not it only writes

```
15 25
```

How can this be fixed?

```
subroutine test(u,n,f)

!input
integer :: n,f,write_unit
real(8) :: u(n+2,n+2)

!lokale
integer :: i,j
real(8) :: vek_x,vek_y


!Skriver vektor verdier til fil som gnuplot skal bruke
open(newunit=write_unit,access='sequential',file='plot.txt',status='unknown')

write(write_unit,*)'# x y vx vy'



vek_x=u(2,2)


!write(write_unit,*) vek_x,f

write(write_unit,*) vek_x,f
write(write_unit,*)''


close(write_unit,status='keep')
```

"Program" that creates different values for `u`

```
do f=1,1000

do j=2,n+1
  do i=2,n+1

u(i,j)=(u(i+1,j)+u(i-1,j)+u(i,j+1)+u(i,j-1))/4


!u(i,j)=(1-omega)*u(i,j)+omega*1/4*(u(i+1,j)+u(i-1,j)+u(i,j+1)+u(i,j-1))


  end do
end do



if (u(2,2) .eq. 15) then
exit
end if

call test(u,n,f)




end do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the file for appending

```
open(newunit=write_unit,access='sequential',file='plot.txt',position='append',status='old',action='write')
```

if that is what you wanted.

For the first time to may want to just create it empty

```
open(newunit=write_unit,access='sequential',file='plot.txt',status='replace')
close(write_unit)
```